# Real-world dice: better to have more small die or one large dice?

Tags: probability

I understand that in a perfect world, 5d4 (5 die with 4 sides each) or 2d10 (2 die with 10 sides each) should have the same probability of a single d20, but what about in the real world? Is it generally better to have a larger (more-sided) dice?

Additional questions:

1) Would 5d4 be more or less fair than a d20?

2) Are d% (2d10, where one is used as the tens unit and the other the ones unit) more or less fair than a d100?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: By "better," I mean "closer in probability to the perfect world scenario." Sorry that was unclear ^^"

Answer (score 4):

> I understand that in a perfect world, 5d4 (5 die with 4 sides each) or 2d10 (2 die with 10 sides each) should have the same probability of a single d20.

Clearly this is not true.   A $\mathsf d20$ will have outcomes in the range of $\{1, .., 20\}$ with no bias (ie: it has a *uniform discrete distribution*).   However, it is impossible to roll less than $5$ on $5\mathsf d4$.   The range of outcomes are only $\{5, .., 20\}$.

> 1) Would 5d4 be more or less fair than a d20?

Fairness is absence of bias, so you are being asked: are the results all equally likely?

*You* can determine that the results are biased, *or not*, by examining the count of ways to obtain some results.

> 2) Are d% (2d10, where one is used as the tens unit and the other the ones unit) more or less fair than a d100?

In this case we are not simply summing the results of each die, rather we are using them to construct a number: $(\mathsf d10)\times 10 + (\mathsf d10)$, though with $0$ being mapped to $100$

Thus here we at least obtain the same sample space as $\mathsf d100$, which is $\{1, .., 100\}$.   Now, can *you* show whether or not the $\mathsf d\%$ method has the same bias as $\mathsf d100$?   That is no bias at all.   Does it?   Why or why not?